# $U(1)$ symmetry transformations in second quantization confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, operators, symmetry, coherent-states

I'm reading Chapter 18 (BEC and Superfluidity) of Girvin and Yang and ran into some confusion.

Let $|\alpha\rangle  = e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{\alpha b^†_0}|0\rangle $, where $\alpha$ is just a complex number. Note that $b_0|\alpha\rangle  = \alpha|\alpha\rangle $. Now suppose we do a $U(1)$ symmetry transformation with $b_{\vec{k}} \rightarrow e^{i\theta}b_{\vec{k}}$ and $b^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}} → e^{-i\theta}b^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}$. I'm fine with everything up to this point, but here comes the confusion:

They state that, under this transformation, $\alpha → e^{i\theta}\alpha$. I am generally confused about this statement, because I find that $|\alpha\rangle\rightarrow |e^{-i\theta}\alpha\rangle $ (just by plugging the above second quantization operator transformations in) which, if anything, I would think implies $\alpha \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\alpha$  instead of $\alpha \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\alpha$. However, to be honest, I'm not convinced of either — since $\alpha$ is just a number it should be invariant under any transformation... right?

It feels like I'm misunderstanding something pretty fundamental/basic here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The arrows might confuse you. Use different variables, instead, which obey the same commutation relation as the untilded ones (canonical transformation),
$$\tilde b_{\vec{k}}  \equiv e^{i\theta}b_{\vec{k}}  ~~~\implies ~~~ \tilde b^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}  \equiv  e^{-i\theta}b^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}~~~\leadsto  \\ \alpha b^†_0 = (\alpha e^{i\theta})~ \tilde b^{\dagger}_0\equiv \tilde  \alpha \tilde b^†_0, \implies \\
\tilde b_0|\tilde \alpha\rangle  = \tilde \alpha|\tilde \alpha\rangle .
 $$

- The *same* coherent state presents as $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\tilde \alpha\rangle$ in the respective bases. To go from one to the other, you tilde everything.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I am now convinced that IF we want to keep our state invariant under this U(1) transformation, $\tilde{\alpha} = e^{i \theta} \alpha$ must hold. However, I don't understand why this state must be invariant under U(1) symmetry transformations. Any insight?

Comment: There is no "want". This transformation is canonical and preserves commutation relations.  The vacuum is invariant, so the Fock space covaries as stated. Why you'd prefer the tilde states to untended ones is up to you....

Comment: I don't want to be the toddler that keeps asking why, but I'm afraid I must ask one more if I want to get to the root of my misunderstanding.
Just for clarity, you're stating that under the U(1) transformation given above, $|\alpha \rangle \rightarrow |\alpha \rangle$ because it preserves the commutation relations. Why do so called "canonical transformations" have this property? If it requires a longer answer than you're able to provide, it would be great if you could direct me to a reference.

Comment: $e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{\alpha b^†_0}|0\rangle $ has eigenvalue α under operation by $ b_0$, and eigenvalue $\tilde \alpha$ under operation by  $\tilde b_0$. Label it by the suitable tilde or lack thereof once you have decided which creation and annihilation operators you choose to use. I'm not sure what the hang up is... I'm not sure you have decided what you actually *mean* by these arrows; not what most do.

Comment: You're right. Getting to the root of what I mean by these arrows was the issue. For completeness/rigor, this is how "the arrow" is defined: $|\alpha\rangle \rightarrow U|\alpha\rangle$ and $b_0 \rightarrow U^†b_0U = e^{i\theta}b_0 \implies Ub^†_0U^† = e^{i\theta}b^†_0$. From this we can derive $U|\alpha\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{\alpha Ub^†_0U^†}|0\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{\alpha e^{i\theta} b^†_0}|0\rangle = |\alpha e^{i\theta}\rangle.$ So $|\alpha\rangle \rightarrow |\alpha e^{i\theta}\rangle$ and $\alpha \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\alpha$